# Video streaming is not working in Safari OS X 13.0.4

Tags: macos, safari, video-streaming, twilio, twilio-api

I am doing testing of the app in Safari OS X 13.0.4 for live video sharing. I am using Twilio's API for that.
But video the streaming having as an issue. please check below link :
https://prnt.sc/qvgfxu

I have also trying to testing using a third-party site this 
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/getDisplayMedia/

But in this case, also the issue is the same, please check below :
https://prnt.sc/qvgfjq

Comment: have you sorted this out? i am facing same issue on my end

Comment: Please checkout the mock device setting in your safari and make it on and then check.